# Setting the ReportSource for the Crystal Report Viewer 2016 control

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I am attempting to convert a vb6 system to VB.Net. I have installed Crystal Reports 2016 - the latest version. I have placed the control "Crystal ActiveX Report Viewer Control 14.0" on a form.

When I attempt to set

```
crViewer.ReportSource = CObj("...\adjrec.rpt")
```

I get the following message:

> "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid." & vbCrLf & "   at CrystalActiveXReportViewerLib14.ICrystalReportViewer12.set_ReportSource(Object pVal)" & vbCrLf & "   at AxCrystalActiveXReportViewerLib14.AxCrystalActiveXReportViewer.set_ReportSource(Object value)" & vbCrLf & "   at CrystalReportViewer2.frmViewer.frmViewer_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\CrystalReportViewer2\frmViewer.vb:line 9"
>   Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in AxInterop.CrystalActiveXReportViewerLib14.dll

How do I set the ReportSource? A worked example will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After being given the run around from Crystal Reports, I have decided to convert to Microsoft Access.

Nev